# Do AncestryDNA questions need an Ancestry.com tag?

Tags: discussion

This is a follow up to the discussion [Reviewing the subscription, website, and ancestry.com tags](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3189/1006)

If a person is asking a question that applies to any autosomal DNA test, but they took their test at AncestryDNA, does it need the Ancestry.com tag?

For a recent example, see [Are centimorgan links additive?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/14762/1006)

Answer (score 2):

My feeling is if a question is purely about analyzing the DNA results, and is NOT about "how do I use the company's website / understand how the company presents my results" then it doesn't need to be *tagged* with the DNA kit's originating company.

In other words, [ancestry.com](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancestry.com) isn't needed unless the question is about understanding Shared Ancestor Hints or DNA Circles or other features which are specific to Ancestry.  Having the information that the test was an AncestryDNA test in the question should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, as soon as I see a question about autosomal DNA (tagged [autosomal-dna](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autosomal-dna)) the first thing I usually want to know is where their test was taken.

If it was from AncestryDNA then I think an [ancestry.com](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancestry.com) tag does no harm, and may sometimes be the only indication.

Consequently, I would propose no change to how we are tagging AncestryDNA questions currently i.e. always tag them [autosomal-dna](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autosomal-dna), optionally tag them [ancestry.com](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancestry.com) too.